# Empty cells when element exist

Tags: jquery

I have a table which contains multiple rows and 5 columns with some data in it:

```
<table>
  <thead>
   ...stuff...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td width="1" class="gui-valign-top">
       .... stuff....
      </td>
      <td>
       <a class="gui-bold" title="Reference / PO box" href="some-url">Reference / PO box</a>
      </td>
      <td width="1">
      .... stuff....
      </td>
      <td width="1">
      .... stuff....
      </td>
      <td width="10%" class="gui-align-right">
        .... stuff....          
      </td>
      <td width="10%" class="gui-align-right">
          .... stuff....           
      </td>
     </tr>
     .... start of new <tr> ....
```

Inside the second cell of any table row there's always a link present with a title. What i try to do is find a specific title and if that title is present then empty all **table cells from that specific row****. The problem is that I can find the correct title but I can't empty the correct cells. Further I try to give the  a black background if the name exist.

My JQUERY so far:

```
          $("#gui-wrapper .gui-table td a").filter(function(){
            return $(this).text() == 'Reference / PO box';   
          }).css("background-color", "#1699f0");
```

This code finds the correct text/td but what do I have to do next to empty all cells but this one with the text in it and then give the  a black background??

I can't work with id's or whatever since this is all created automatically.

Anybody? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To empty *all* the cells from that row (including the cell with the specific `<a>` element):

```
$("#gui-wrapper .gui-table td a").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == 'Reference / PO box';   
}).closest('tr').find('td').empty();
```

```js
$(".gui-table td a").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == 'Reference / PO box';   
}).closest('tr').find('td').empty();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="gui-table">
  <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td width="1" class="gui-valign-top">
       .... stuff....
      </td>
      <td>
       <a class="gui-bold" title="Reference / PO box" href="some-url">Reference / PO box</a>
      </td>
      <td width="1">
      .... stuff....
      </td>
      <td width="1">
      .... stuff....
      </td>
      <td width="10%" class="gui-align-right">
        .... stuff....          
      </td>
      <td width="10%" class="gui-align-right">
          .... stuff....           
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td width="1" class="gui-valign-top">
       .... stuff....
      </td>
      <td>
       <a class="gui-bold" title="a different title" href="some-url">a different title indeed</a>
      </td>
      <td width="1">
      .... stuff....
      </td>
      <td width="1">
      .... stuff....
      </td>
      <td width="10%" class="gui-align-right">
        .... stuff....          
      </td>
      <td width="10%" class="gui-align-right">
          .... stuff....           
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

To empty all the cells *except* the cell containing the given `<a>` element:

```
$("#gui-wrapper .gui-table td a").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == 'Reference / PO box';   
}).closest('td').siblings().empty();

$(".gui-table td a").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == 'Reference / PO box';   
}).closest('td').siblings().empty();
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="gui-table">
  <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td width="1" class="gui-valign-top">
       .... stuff....
      </td>
      <td>
       <a class="gui-bold" title="Reference / PO box" href="some-url">Reference / PO box</a>
      </td>
      <td width="1">
      .... stuff....
      </td>
      <td width="1">
      .... stuff....
      </td>
      <td width="10%" class="gui-align-right">
        .... stuff....          
      </td>
      <td width="10%" class="gui-align-right">
          .... stuff....           
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td width="1" class="gui-valign-top">
       .... stuff....
      </td>
      <td>
       <a class="gui-bold" title="a different title" href="some-url">a different title indeed</a>
      </td>
      <td width="1">
      .... stuff....
      </td>
      <td width="1">
      .... stuff....
      </td>
      <td width="10%" class="gui-align-right">
        .... stuff....          
      </td>
      <td width="10%" class="gui-align-right">
          .... stuff....           
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Comment: Just add a call to `css('background-color','black')`, or `addClass('blackBackgroundClassName')`, in between `filter()` and `closest()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this,

```
$("#gui-wrapper .gui-table td a:contains('Reference / PO box')").closest("td").next() empty();
```